# Spring Hibernate - Local Session Factory Bean

Tags: spring, hibernate

Spring hibernate - LocalSessionFactoryBean without hibernate template

```
    package com.main.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.main.entity.BaseEntity;

public abstract class BaseDao<T extends BaseEntity> {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void add(T entity) {
        this.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }

    @Transactional
    public T getEntityById(Class<T> clazz, Serializable id) {
        return this.getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
    }

    public void saveEntity(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.getCurrentSession().update(clazz);
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }



}


    package com.main.dao;

import com.main.entity.Customer;

public class CustomerDaoImpl extends BaseDao<Customer> {



}

    package com.main.service;

import com.main.dao.CustomerDaoImpl;
import com.main.entity.Customer;

public class CustomerServiceImpl implements Service<Customer> {

    private CustomerDaoImpl customerDaoImpl;


    public Customer getEntityById(Long id) {
        return this.customerDaoImpl.getEntityById(Customer.class, id);
    }


    public CustomerDaoImpl getCustomerDaoImpl() {
        return customerDaoImpl;
    }


    public void setCustomerDaoImpl(CustomerDaoImpl customerDaoImpl) {
        this.customerDaoImpl = customerDaoImpl;
    }



}

    package com.main.engine;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.main.entity.Customer;
import com.main.service.CustomerServiceImpl;

public class StartEngine {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StartEngine.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    LOGGER.info("Logging started");

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

    CustomerServiceImpl customerServiceImpl = (CustomerServiceImpl)applicationContext.getBean("customerServiceImpl");

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer = customerServiceImpl.getEntityById(2L);

    System.out.println(customer.getName());

    }
}
```

`spring-config.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config/>

    <import resource="dataSource.xml" />

    <import resource="hibernate-session-manager.xml" />

    <bean id="customerServiceImpl" class="com.main.service.CustomerServiceImpl">
        <property name="customerDaoImpl" ref="customerDaoImpl" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerDaoImpl" class="com.main.dao.CustomerDaoImpl" parent="baseDao" />

    <bean id="baseDao" class="com.main.dao.BaseDao" abstract="true">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

`hibernate-session-manager.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
            <value>customer-hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/> 

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

POM.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.spring.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringHibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I am getting the exception as :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:599)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.main.engine.StartEngine.main(StartEngine.java:18)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

And if i remove context:annotation-config from spring config
then the exception changes to

```
          Exception in thread "main"      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'transactionManagerBeanName' of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Bean property 'transactionManagerBeanName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.main.engine.StartEngine.main(StartEngine.java:18)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'transactionManagerBeanName' of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]: Bean property 'transactionManagerBeanName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1024)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:900)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    ... 13 more
```

Sorry for posting the question like this.

Comment: You most probably forgot to add a jar and/or are using incompatible spring jar files. Show your dependencies in the pom.xml or build.gradle file.

Comment: I have added the POM as requested

Comment: You're using two different versions of spring jar files: 3.0.5.RELEASE and 4.0.3.RELEASE, and a very old, obsolete, spring-hibernate artifact, that is unnecessary.